# how solve cron job proplem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I create cron job in rails project in lib/tasks

```
namespace :job do
 desc "TODO"
 task finish_job: :environment do
 jobs = Job.where(end_date:Date.today())
  if jobs != []
    print('Found jobs!')
    
  for job in jobs
        promoter_ids_in_promoter_requests = job.promoters_requests_jobs.where(status: "accept").pluck(:promoter_id)
        
        promoters = Promoter.where(id:promoters).update_all(is_enrolled: false)
    end
else
    print("No jobs!")
end
end 

end
```

when i run this command `bundle exec whenever --update-crontab`
i get this error

```
 NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be 
 removed on or after 2019-12-01.
 Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from 
 /home/omnia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/specifications/mimemagic- 
 0.3.3.gemspec:16.
 NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be 
 removed on or after 2019-12-01.
```

How solve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

These are not errors but are deprecation warnings.
please post all the error codes if the command fails.